# nHibernate criteria for reversed LIKE

Tags: c#, nhibernate, icriteria, criteria-api

I have the following two entities:

public class Entity1
{
   public IList e2 { get; set; }
}

public class Entity2
{
   public string Title { get; set; }
}

I only have repository for Entity1, I know I can do a LIKE query with the following criteria:

criteria.CreateAlias("e2", "e1e2").Add(Restrictions.LIKE("Title", "needle", Match.Anywhere);

But I need to search the reverse like:

Restrictions.LIKE("needle", "Title", Match.Anywhere)

How can I do it?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "reverse like"? Clearly you're not trying to find something like "Title" in a `needle` property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it's available out of the box.

You can either create it using a SQLCriterion, or use HQL.